# Creating a progress bar with tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple progress bar that simply shows me the progress of my program as it runs. The code I have written is the following:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
progress = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient = 'horizontal', length = 120)
progress.pack()
progress.config(mode = 'indeterminate', maximum = 100, value = 5)
progress.start()


(Program goes here)
```

However I get the following error

```
BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

at
df99 = pd.read_excel(os.path.commonpath(excel_file), sheet_name='Sheet1',skiprows=11, usecols=[2,3,6,8])
```

What would cause this? I do not really understand the error.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the code you posted gives you this error. The error must come from another part of your code that you haven't shown. Please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: What is in `(Program goes here)`? Seems relatively important given there is no zip file in your code

Comment: There is not zip file used in my code at all, does tkinter require the use of zip file or something?

Comment: There's nothing requiring any zip file functionality in the code you posted. The error must come from somewhere within `(Program goes here)`.

Comment: The error is completely unrelated to the statusbar.

Comment: I have updated the question. The error seems to come from a line where I read in an excel file into a new pandas dataframe

Comment: MaxB: You didn't update your question properly, as @BryanOakley said, it has *nothing* to do with the `ttk.Progressbar`.

Comment: You really should not be calling `os.path.commonpath()` on the filename.

Comment: I am unable to figure out what would cause this error because it only happens when attempting to implement the progress bar. If I delete the code above, everything works fine.